# Kafka Streams: How to fix Serde casting error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I simulate word count case with using aggregate function, I encounter Serde casting issue.

```
Exception in thread "aggregation-transformation-application-43485635-2d3c-4edc-b13c-c6505a793d18-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.maybeUpdateTimestamp(RecordQueue.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.poll(RecordQueue.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.nextRecord(PartitionGroup.java:100)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:199)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:420)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:890)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Size of data received by IntegerDeserializer is not 4
```

Although, I defined Serdes for each task, it throws SerializationException.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class AggregationTransformation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //prepare config
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "aggregation-transformation-application");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> kStream = builder.stream("agg-table-source-topic");
        KStream<String, Integer> kStreamFormatted = kStream.flatMapValues((key, value) ->
                Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+"))).selectKey((key, value) -> value)
                .mapValues(value -> 1);

        kStreamFormatted.groupByKey(Grouped.<String,Integer>as(null)
                .withValueSerde(Serdes.Integer()))
                .aggregate(() -> 0,
                        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + newValue,
                        Materialized.<String, Integer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                                as("aggregated-stream-store")
                                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                .withValueSerde(Serdes.Integer())
                ).toStream().to("agg-output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));

        Topology topology = builder.build();
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                kafkaStreams.close();
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            kafkaStreams.start();
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

For first entry as "John Smith" to producer console, I expect that ouput topic (agg-output-topic) should have

```
John 1
Smith 1
```

And if I enter the same input to producer (agg-table-source-topic), then output topic should have do aggregation and result should be

```
John 2
Smith 2
```

I appriciate for your help.

Comment: I cannot spot a bug. Maybe try to set a breakpoint on the `deserializer` to see what the data comes from exactly. Also, it seems you could simplify your code (eg, using `map()` instead of `selectKey()`+`mapValues()` -- and if you want to count, just do a `count()` instead of `aggregate()` ?

Comment: @Onur Tokat, Didn't you change types for aggregation? ex. from Long to Integer? For testing purpose please remove all intermediate topic and start your application again

Comment: Could the problem be this code: `Grouped.<String,Integer>as(null)`? Why are you using this function to set the name of the re-partition topic to `null`? Why don't you use `.groupByKey()` instead of `.groupByKey(Grouped.<String,Integer>as(null).withValueSerde(Serdes.Integer()))`?

Comment: @Michael G. Noll, According to "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters." exception definition, I set the Serdes for GroupByKey(...). I assume that this way guarantees expected Serde's types. I filled as null for Grouped name, this behavior does not create any problem in my opinion.

Comment: @wardziniak, yes I changed from Long to Integer, because summation in the aggregate function inherently behaves as Integer. Otherwise I should define Long type casting for aggValue and newValue. I restarted server and topics many times while I was changing types.

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax, I am trying to debug the last serialization task. Yes using count for word count case is meaningful, but I want to see same result using aggregate. Theorically, I should see if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SerializationException` means that your `Deserializer` (in your case `IntegerDeserializer`) cannot deserializer message - cannot convert bytes to some object (`Integer`)

How you have written in comment you have changed types from `Long` to `Integer`. I think you first start your application with type `Long` and process several messages and than change type to `Integer`. Your application save intermediate result in changelog topic and later with *new* type and Deserializer (Serdes) it cannot deserialize and throw an exception.

If you change a type in your application you have to *delete* all changelog topic that are created during processing. Otherwise `SerializationException` might occur.

Comment: wardziniak, you are right! This is awesome lesson-learned case, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> When I simulate word count case with using aggregate function [...]

Your setup looks very complicated.  Why don't you just do the following?

```java
final KTable<String, Long> aggregated = builder.stream("agg-table-source-topic");
  .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))
  .groupBy((keyIgnored, word) -> word)
  // Normally, you'd use `count()` here and be done with it.
  // But you mentioned you intentionally want to use `aggregate(...)`.
  .aggregate(
      () -> 0L,
      (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + 1L,
      Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("aggregate-store").withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()))

aggregated.toStream().to("agg-output-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

That is, compared to the normal WordCount example, all you have to do is to replace:

```java
  .count()
```

with

```java
  .aggregate(
      () -> 0L,
      (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> aggValue + 1L,
      Materialized.<String, Long, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("aggregate-store").withValueSerde(Serdes.Long()))
```

Note that the example code above using `Long`, not `Integer`, but of course you could change that.